# USocket on SBCL: connection refused (Drakma and Dex)

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, ccl, usocket

Running simple HTTP-request:

- with `dexador` or `drakma`
- and on SBCL 1.4.14
- and on OS X 10.13.6
- with `(ql:client-version)` equals to "2017-03-06" and `(defvar qlqs-info:*version* "2015-01-28"` (I've just installed Quicklisp from https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/ via https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp)
- via Emacs+SLIME or just from the command line using only SBCL

```
(dex:get "http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
```

fails with the error (`dex` stacktrace)

```
Condition USOCKET:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR was signalled.
   [Condition of type USOCKET:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR]

Backtrace:
  0: (USOCKET::HANDLE-CONDITION #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR {1008622AF3}> #<USOCKET:STREAM-USOCKET {1008622583}>)
  1: (SB-KERNEL::%SIGNAL #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR {1008622AF3}>)
  2: (ERROR SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR :ERRNO 61 :SYSCALL "connect")
  3: (SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET-ERROR "connect" 61)
  4: (SB-BSD-SOCKETS::CALL-WITH-SOCKET-ADDR #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:INET-SOCKET 127.0.0.1:59367, fd: 17 {1008622473}> (#(127 0 0 1) 8000) #<CLOSURE (FLET SB-BSD-SOCKETS::WITH-SOCKET-ADDR-THUNK :IN SB-BSD-SOCKETS:..
  5: ((:METHOD SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET-CONNECT (SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET)) #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:INET-SOCKET 127.0.0.1:59367, fd: 17 {1008622473}> #(127 0 0 1) 8000) [fast-method]
  6: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-22" :IN USOCKET:SOCKET-CONNECT))
  7: (USOCKET:SOCKET-CONNECT "localhost" 8000 :PROTOCOL :STREAM :ELEMENT-TYPE (UNSIGNED-BYTE 8) :TIMEOUT 10 :DEADLINE NIL :NODELAY T :LOCAL-HOST NIL :LOCAL-PORT NIL)
  8: ((LABELS DEXADOR.BACKEND.USOCKET::MAKE-NEW-CONNECTION :IN DEXADOR.BACKEND.USOCKET:REQUEST) #<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTP http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
  9: (DEXADOR.BACKEND.USOCKET:REQUEST #<unavailable argument> :METHOD :GET)
 10: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (DEXADOR:GET "http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts") #<NULL-LEXEN..
 11: (EVAL (DEXADOR:GET "http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"))
```

or (`drakma` stacktrace)

```
Condition USOCKET:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR was signalled.
   [Condition of type USOCKET:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1003CE8413}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (USOCKET::HANDLE-CONDITION #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR {1005657693}> #<USOCKET:STREAM-USOCKET {1005657123}>)
  1: (SB-KERNEL::%SIGNAL #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR {1005657693}>)
  2: (ERROR SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR :ERRNO 61 :SYSCALL "connect")
  3: (SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET-ERROR "connect" 61)
  4: (SB-BSD-SOCKETS::CALL-WITH-SOCKET-ADDR #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:INET-SOCKET 127.0.0.1:59799, fd: 12 {1005657013}> (#(127 0 0 1) 8000) #<CLOSURE (FLET SB-BSD-SOCKETS::WITH-SOCKET-ADDR-THUNK :IN SB-BSD-SOCKETS:..
  5: ((:METHOD SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET-CONNECT (SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET)) #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:INET-SOCKET 127.0.0.1:59799, fd: 12 {1005657013}> #(127 0 0 1) 8000) [fast-method]
  6: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-22" :IN USOCKET:SOCKET-CONNECT))
  7: (USOCKET:SOCKET-CONNECT "localhost" 8000 :PROTOCOL :STREAM :ELEMENT-TYPE FLEXI-STREAMS:OCTET :TIMEOUT 20 :DEADLINE NIL :NODELAY :IF-SUPPORTED :LOCAL-HOST NIL :LOCAL-PORT NIL)
  8: (DRAKMA:HTTP-REQUEST #<PURI:URI http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts>)
  9: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (DRAKMA:HTTP-REQUEST "http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 10: (EVAL (DRAKMA:HTTP-REQUEST "http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"))
 11: (SWANK::EVAL-REGION "(drakma:http-request \"http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts\") ..)
 12: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL))
 13: (SWANK-REPL::TRACK-PACKAGE #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {10056566CB}>)
 14: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-RETRY-RESTART "Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request." #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {100565666B}>)
 15: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BUFFER-SYNTAX NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {100565664B}>)
 16: (SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL "(drakma:http-request \"http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts\") ..)
 17: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(drakma:http-request \"http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts\") ..)
 18: (EVAL (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(drakma:http-request \"http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts\") ..)
 19: (SWANK:EVAL-FOR-EMACS (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(drakma:http-request \"http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts\") ..)
 20: (SWANK::PROCESS-REQUESTS NIL)
 21: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 22: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 23: (SWANK/SBCL::CALL-WITH-BREAK-HOOK #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {1003CF008B}>)
 24: ((FLET SWANK/BACKEND:CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK :IN "/Users/ihar/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.22/swank/sbcl.lisp") #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HA..
 25: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BINDINGS ((*STANDARD-INPUT* . #1=#<SWANK/GRAY::SLIME-INPUT-STREAM {1003BEA693}>) (*STANDARD-OUTPUT* . #2=#<SWANK/GRAY::SLIME-OUTPUT-STREAM {1003CC8CF3}>) (*TRACE-OUTPUT* . #2#) (*ERR..
 26: (SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS #<SWANK::MULTITHREADED-CONNECTION {10032427F3}> NIL)
 27: ((FLET SB-UNIX::BODY :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
 28: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-4" :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
 29: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
 30: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-1" :IN SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX))
 31: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX #<CLOSURE (FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE) {3A67D6B}> #<SB-THREAD:MUTEX "thread result lock" owner: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "..
 32: (SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1003CE8413}> NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::SPAWN-REPL-THREAD) {1003CE83BB}> NIL)
 33: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp")
 34: ("foreign function: new_thread_trampoline")
 35: ("foreign function: _pthread_body")
 36: ("foreign function: _pthread_body")
 37: ("foreign function: thread_start")
```

Running the same request on *Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.11.5  (DarwinX8664)* works good.

Does somebody know the reason?

Comment: What is your Quicklisp version ? Can you show the Drakma stacktrace ?

Comment: @Ehvince I've updated the post

Comment: So the QL is quite old. Would you try again after an update ? `(ql:update-dist "quicklisp")`.

Comment: @Ehvince great thanks, now everything works. I missed the "update-dist" line in the docs and updated only the client after installation.

Comment: Cool ! Do you have anything in your ~/.sbclrc btw ?

Comment: @Ehvince yeah, just that, does it matter somehow? `;;; The following lines added by ql:add-to-init-file:
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))`

Comment: no that's good. I've been surprised myself once so I'd better ask :)

Comment: @Ehvince found today that this still is the problem, I've uninstalled everything and installed with `roswell` fresh and new, but still fails. Created a new question with new details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638335/drakma-and-dexador-both-fails-at-usocket-call-while-requesting-localhost-only-r

Comment: beware that a fresh Roswell install doesn't necessarily include the newest Quicklisp distribution. And the Roswell's QL version is different than the default one in ~/quicklisp/local-projects.

Comment: @Ehvince seems fine: `"quicklisp": 2019-02-02` and `up-to-date client, version 2017-03-06`

Comment: the question is answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638335/drakma-and-dexador-both-fails-at-usocket-call-while-requesting-localhost-only-r/54711949#54711949

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drakma and Dexador both fails at USocket call while requesting localhost only, requesting the internet works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638335/drakma-and-dexador-both-fails-at-usocket-call-while-requesting-localhost-only-r)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and I noticed my local services which Drakma tried to reach were ipv6 based, so they listened at ::1, when I set those service to listen at 127.0.0.1:xxxx explicitly instead of localhost:xxxx they became ipv4 and Drakma didn't complain any more.

Comment: yes, thank you. there is a link in the comments, the question is closed