# Drakma and Dexador both fails at USocket call while requesting localhost only, requesting the internet works fine

Tags: sockets, common-lisp, usocket, drakma

There is an unexplained behavior for me for the moment, appreciate any clues.

## Background

I have a locally running instance of wordpress via PHP built-in development webserver `php -S localhost:8000 -t /doc/root/wordpress`. The site works, I can fetch it with `curl "http://localhost:8000/"` successfully, I can open it in a web browser also.

But simple programs like:

```
(drakma:http-request "http://localhost:8000/")
```

or

```
(dexador:get "http://localhost:8000/")
```

-- both fail.

`drakma` fails with the backtrace:

```
Condition USOCKET:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR was signalled.
   [Condition of type USOCKET:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1004CC9B93}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (USOCKET::HANDLE-CONDITION #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR {100435B3A3}> #<USOCKET:STREAM-USOCKET {100435AE33}>)
  1: (SB-KERNEL::%SIGNAL #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR {100435B3A3}>)
  2: (ERROR SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR :ERRNO 61 :SYSCALL "connect")
  3: (SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET-ERROR "connect" 61)
  4: (SB-BSD-SOCKETS::CALL-WITH-SOCKET-ADDR #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:INET-SOCKET 127.0.0.1:49431, fd: 16 {100435AD23}> (#(127 0 0 1) 8000) #<CLOSURE (FLET SB-BSD-SOCKETS::WITH-SOCKET-ADDR-THUNK :IN SB-BSD-SOCKETS:..
  5: ((:METHOD SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET-CONNECT (SB-BSD-SOCKETS:SOCKET)) #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:INET-SOCKET 127.0.0.1:49431, fd: 16 {100435AD23}> #(127 0 0 1) 8000) [fast-method]
  6: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-22" :IN USOCKET:SOCKET-CONNECT))
  7: (USOCKET:SOCKET-CONNECT "localhost" 8000 :PROTOCOL :STREAM :ELEMENT-TYPE FLEXI-STREAMS:OCTET :TIMEOUT 20 :DEADLINE NIL :NODELAY :IF-SUPPORTED :LOCAL-HOST NIL :LOCAL-PORT NIL)
  8: (DRAKMA:HTTP-REQUEST #<PURI:URI http://localhost:8000/>)
  9: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (DRAKMA:HTTP-REQUEST "http://localhost:8000/") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 10: (EVAL (DRAKMA:HTTP-REQUEST "http://localhost:8000/"))
 11: (SWANK::EVAL-REGION "(drakma:http-request \"http://localhost:8000/\") ..)
 12: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL))
 13: (SWANK-REPL::TRACK-PACKAGE #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {100435A53B}>)
 14: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-RETRY-RESTART "Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request." #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {100435A4DB}>)
 15: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BUFFER-SYNTAX NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL) {100435A4BB}>)
 16: (SWANK-REPL::REPL-EVAL "(drakma:http-request \"http://localhost:8000/\") ..)
 17: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(drakma:http-request \"http://localhost:8000/\") ..)
 18: (EVAL (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(drakma:http-request \"http://localhost:8000/\") ..)
 19: (SWANK:EVAL-FOR-EMACS (SWANK-REPL:LISTENER-EVAL "(drakma:http-request \"http://localhost:8000/\") ..)
 20: (SWANK::PROCESS-REQUESTS NIL)
 21: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 22: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS))
 23: (SWANK/SBCL::CALL-WITH-BREAK-HOOK #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {1004CD008B}>)
 24: ((FLET SWANK/BACKEND:CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK :IN "/Users/ihar/.roswell/lisp/slime/2019.02.02/swank/sbcl.lisp") #<FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {..
 25: (SWANK::CALL-WITH-BINDINGS ((*STANDARD-INPUT* . #<SWANK/GRAY::SLIME-INPUT-STREAM {1004BC9E93}>)) #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS) {1004CD00AB}>)
 26: (SWANK::HANDLE-REQUESTS #<SWANK::MULTITHREADED-CONNECTION {10079AA873}> NIL)
 27: ((FLET SB-UNIX::BODY :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
 28: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-4" :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
 29: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
 30: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-1" :IN SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX))
 31: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX #<CLOSURE (FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE) {3A67D6B}> #<SB-THREAD:MUTEX "thread result lock" owner: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "..
 32: (SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1004CC9B93}> NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SWANK-REPL::SPAWN-REPL-THREAD) {1004CC9B3B}> NIL)
 33: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp")
 34: ("foreign function: new_thread_trampoline")
 35: ("foreign function: _pthread_body")
 36: ("foreign function: _pthread_body")
 37: ("foreign function: thread_start")
```

Interesting, if I change the URI to any other on the internet:

```
(drakma:http-request "https://stackoverflow.com")
```

-- then it works fine.

So the problem, probably, somewhere in the context of my local machine and local php-server. What could be wrong with these simple function calls?

## My notes

- in the backtrace I see this line `(USOCKET:SOCKET-CONNECT "localhost" 8000 :PROTOCOL :STREAM :ELEMENT-TYPE FLEXI-STREAMS:OCTET :TIMEOUT 20 :DEADLINE NIL :NODELAY :IF-SUPPORTED :LOCAL-HOST NIL :LOCAL-PORT NIL)`. The keys `:local-host` and `:local-port` are both `nil`. Probably that's the issue, because according to the [usocket specs](https://common-lisp.net/project/usocket/api-docs.shtml) those params are responsible for calling `bind()` on local address (is it somehow different than calling non-local address?).
- I also haven't found in the specs for `drakma:http-request` any special parameters to specify that I'm requesting a local server. According to the example, https://edicl.github.io/drakma/#ex-basic-auth, requesting any URI is simple and goes without any differentiation of 'local address' vs non-local.

## Summing up

- Why requesting "http://localhost:8000" doesn't work with `drakma` or `dexador`. Does anybody can confirm the same behavior for local web servers?
- Is the `bind()` syscall somehow different for local and non-local addresses?

---

P.S. I already asked the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506364/usocket-on-sbcl-connection-refused-drakma-and-dex) and first it seemed like the problem was with old software versions. Now I found additional details of the problem and rephrased it, so I'm making another question here.

---

## Update 1

Maybe, the problem is connected to the particular PHP built-it webserver for development, because the issue is reproducible only with the PHP webserver + SBCL + Drakma. But PHP webserver serves fine for `curl`, a Go client, a web browser.

PHP version:

> PHP 7.3.1 (cli) (built: Jan 10 2019 13:16:34) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.3.1, Copyright (c) 1998-2018
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.3.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

-- installed with `brew install php`.

### Steps to reproduce

The server:

```
php -S localhost:7070
```

Then try with clients:

```
curl "http://localhost:7070"
```

-- works fine (status code 404 is expected and received).

Lisp:

```
(drakma:http-request "http://localhost:7070")
```

-- fails (status code 404 is expected but `connection refused` is returned).

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://pastebin.com/raw/4Fqd4HYS

Comment: @coredump your case works fine for me also, but I still have this PHP built-in server running locally which I can access with `curl`, web browser and with a program written in Go without problems (client code: https://play.golang.org/p/PRX8l3cbK9M), but still cannot fetch with SBCL+Drakma

Comment: @coredump this is the server in Go: https://play.golang.org/p/v1YxrnHzHd2 -- no problem fetching it with SBCL+Drakma also

Comment: @coredump I've followed your example and updated the post with steps to reproduce my particular problem

Comment: I can reproduce that (on Linux+SBCL), but I have no idea currently why this fails. Will try again a later time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who wants details, there is a [discussion](https://github.com/edicl/drakma/issues/98) where Stas Boukarev helped to debug the problem.

Running `php -S localhost:7070` starts a server listening on *ipv6* address on my computer, so requesting the *ipv4* address `127.0.0.1:7070` doesn't work in that case.

So the server must be started with explicit *ipv4* address `php -S 127.0.0.1:7070` instead to work correctly.